# Share wishlist email not being sent?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, email-translation

I'm using CE 1.9.1.0 and my **cron.sh** file is being run every 5 minutes on my server. I have also set up the template within **Configuration -> Transnational Emails** but the template is still not being sent.

I'm on the verge of launching the site but want to make sure all functionality works before I do. If any additional information is needed I can provide it, my site is also live (http://decormarket.com)

Are there any other steps I'm looking over? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check

1. if your "FROM" email is properly configured (System > Configuration > Store email addresses, should be a real existing Email)
2. if email daemon (sendmail, etc..) is running and properly configured

In the most cases 1. is a reason of the issue.
By the way: can you receive any other kinds of emails from your site?
What have you specified in System > Configuration > Customers > Wishlist > ShareOptions > EmailSender??

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Turns out I just had the wrong template selected within *Configuration > Customers > Wishlist > Share Options*. I just tried it again and of course it worked :)